# $(0,0,\dots,0,1), (1,2,3,\dots,n-1,0)$ are in the same orbit under the map given by $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \to (a_2, \dots, a_n, (a_n+a_1 \bmod n)).$

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}_n^n \to \mathbb{Z}_n^n$ be the map given by $(a_1, \dots, a_n) \to (a_2, \dots, a_n, a_n+a_1).$ Prove that there exists $k$ such that $f^k(1,2,3,\dots,n-1,0) = (0,0,\dots,0,1).$

I have proved this result for $n \le 6$ and when $n$ is prime. I have shown $f$ is invertible, and more specifically, as linear transformation it has determinant $1.$ Unfortunately, I cannot make any further progress. If it helps, the real problem I am trying to solve has $(0,0,\dots, 1)$ replaced by $(0,0,\dots,a)$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}_n,$ i.e. we only need to show one of $n$ possible choices works. However, I figured that we can always show $a=1$ works.

Any ideas, hints, or approaches? A linear algebra approach via diagonalizing $f$ doesn't seem promising because the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are very messy to work with. Maybe there's another path through linear algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is invertible and $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^n$ is finite, the inverse of $f$ is a power of $f$.

This means it suffices to go the other way, from $(0,0,...,1)$ to $(1,2,...,n-1,0)$ but that is easy to do:
$$f^n(0,0,...,1)) = (1,1,...,1)$$
and then
$$f(1,1,...,1) = (1,1,...,1,2)$$
$$f(1,1,...,2) = (1,1,...,1,2,3)$$
and so on until we reach
$$(1,2,3,...,n) = (1,2,3,...,n-1,0)$$
since $n=0$.

In total, we've shown that $f^{2n}(0,0,...,0,1) = (1,2,...,n-1,0)$ which means that
$$(0,0,...,0,1) = f^{-2n}(1,2,...,n-1,0) = (f^{-1})^{2n}$$
but as remarked above, $f^{-1}$ can be written as $f^k$ for some $k$, so $f^{2nk}$ will do the job.

Comment: Rats! I had tried working from $(0,0,\dots,1)$ while checking $n=6$ at one point, but got up to $(3,4,5,6,7,9) = (3,4,5,0,2,3),$ accidentally skipping over $(1,2,3,4,5,0).$